# Different tickFormat for Axis and useInteractiveGuideline D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I am building a stackedAreaChart in NVD3 for one of my projects. My data for this chart is an array of dictionaries, where each dictionary is similar to the one below:

`{x: 0, y: 1000, tickValue: 'Sunday'}`

I have created a mapping of (x,tickValue) and have written a custom tickFormat function which would return the `tickValue` corresponding to the `x` value for the X-Axis. So my X-Axis would have the values as Sunday, Monday, etc. And I want the `x` values (0, 1, 2, ...) in the Interactive Guideline tooltip. But it seems like NVD3 is using the same tickFormat function while showing the Interactive Guideline tooltip.

However, I wanted to use the `x` value of the data in the Interactive Guideline tooltip. So is it possible to have two different custom methods, one for populating the X-Axis, and the other for Interactive Guideline in NVD3?